# Failed to open .ini file and hanging thread

Tags: android-emulator

```
Emulator: [5456]:WARNING:android/android-emu/android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:232:Failed to open .ini file C:\Users\UMAIR\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for writing.
```

6:29 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU1 thread'. No response for 15002 ms

Comment: Does the file exist? Is another process using it?

Comment: yes the file exits

Comment: yes the file exists and it is read only.what does it mean that that another process using it???

Answer (score 0):

If it's read-only, that may be the problem. The error says: `Failed to open file for writing`. Try removing the read-only attribute from the file.

If that doesn't work, check the permissions on the file. Maybe your Emulator does not have rights to modify the file.

Finally, try to find out if another process/program is using/locking your file. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) you can find some ways to achieve this.